# Docker container stop when mac sleep

Tags: macos, docker

Since a few days my docker containers are all stopping when the computer sleep for something like 20min.
It was not doing that before, I have no logs in my containers, everything seems fine.
Do you have any idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same, but I found solution at Github: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/85#issuecomment-314054172

> I'm now running 17.06.0-ce-mac17 (18432) and after changing the settings to "No proxy" I haven't had any problems.

Comment: Docker 17.06.0-ce-mac19 with fix for this issue was released